# Как передать информацию на UIPageViewController через ViewController

Tags: swift, uikit, uiviewcontroller

У меня есть три файла:

Файл `UIPageViewController`:

```
let imageDefault = UIImage(named: "user")
var pages = [userInfo]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let page1 = userInfo(quastionLabel: "Как вас зовут?", answerTextField: "Введите ваше имя", userPhoto: nil)
    let page2 = userInfo(quastionLabel: "Как ваша фамилия?", answerTextField: "Введите вашу фамилию", userPhoto: imageDefault)
    let page3 = userInfo(quastionLabel: "Bio", answerTextField: "Напишите что-нибудь", userPhoto: imageDefault)
    let page4 = userInfo(quastionLabel: "Как вас зовут?", answerTextField: "Введите ваше имя", userPhoto: imageDefault)
    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(page3)
    pages.append(page4)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    setViewControllers([arrayPageVC[0]], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK: -CreateViewControllers
lazy var arrayPageVC: [UserStartViewController] = {
    var pagesVC = [UserStartViewController]()
    for page in pages{
        pagesVC.append(UserStartViewController(withUser: page))
    }
    return pagesVC
}()
```

И его расширение:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewController = viewController as? UserStartViewController else {return nil}
    if let index = arrayPageVC.firstIndex(of: viewController){
        if index > 0{
            return arrayPageVC[index - 1]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let viewController = viewController as? UserStartViewController else {return nil}
    if let index = arrayPageVC.firstIndex(of: viewController){
        if index < pages.count - 1{
            return arrayPageVC[index + 1]
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pages.count
}
func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
```

Есть `ViewController`, на котором будет вся информация:

```
var label: UILabel{
    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2-100, 
                         y: self.view.bounds.height/6, width: 200, height: 50)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    label.text = "Default text"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}

var textField: UITextField{
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2-(self.view.bounds.size.width-10)/2, y: self.view.bounds.height-300, width: self.view.bounds.size.width-10, height: 31))
    textField.borderStyle = .none
    textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    textField.textAlignment = .center
    textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    textField.placeholder = "Default placeholder"
    return textField
}

var userImage: UIImageView{
    var image = UIImageView()
    let imageDefault = UIImage(named: "user")
    image = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.size.width/2-75, y: self.view.bounds.height/4, width: 150, height: 150))
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 50
    image.layer.masksToBounds = true
    image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    image.image = imageDefault
    return image
}

lazy var subView: [UIView] = [self.label, self.textField, self.userImage]

//MARK: -Init
init(withUser: userInfo){
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    edgesForExtendedLayout = []
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    label.text = withUser.quastionLabel
    textField.placeholder = withUser.answerTextField
    userImage.image = withUser.userPhoto
    
    for view in subView{
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
    
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

и есть модель:

```
import UIKit

struct userInfo {
    var quastionLabel = String()
    var answerTextField = String()
    var userPhoto : UIImage?
}
```

При запуске приложения объекты, которые я создаю в `PageViewController` не передаются в `init` `ViewController`. Проблема в инициализаторе? или во мне?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте во ViewController subview как lazy func, иначе они у вас каждый раз вычисляются (computed) при обращении к ним и их значения затираются:

```
lazy var label: UILabel = {
...
}()

lazy var textField: UITextField = {
...
}()

lazy var userImage: UIImageView = {
...
}()
```